# find the three closest in terms of characteristics

Tags: r, loops, apply, tidyverse, matching

```
library("tidyverse")
demo1 <- as.data.frame(tribble(
  ~cut,         ~freq, ~distance,
  "Fair",       1610,    4,
  "Good",       4906,    100,
  "Very Good",  12082,   45,
  "Premium",    13791,    50,
  "Ideal",      21551,  34,
  "Very good",  14938,  60
))

demo2 <- as.data.frame(tribble(
  ~cut,         ~freq, ~distance,
  "Very Good",  403,    14,
  "Fair",       3920,    25,
  "Premium",  5938,   5,
  "Good",    4593,    40,
  "Ideal",      21551,   2.4,
))
```

For each observation (row) in the demo1 data, I would like to find nearest three in terms of distance related to the row in demo2 data. The result needs to be combined into a same .csv file.

My code implemented shows errors.

```
Result<-data.frame()
for (k in 1:nrow(demo1)) {
  Result <- demo2 %>% 
    filter(abs(demo2$distance-demo1$distance[k])????)
  print(Result)
  }
```

Can anyone please help me with this, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try the code below

```
out <- bind_cols(
  demo2,
  tibble(nearest = lapply(
    split(
      abs(do.call("-", expand.grid(demo1$distance, demo2$distance))),
      ceiling(seq(nrow(demo1) * nrow(demo2)) / nrow(demo1))
    ),
    function(x) demo1[head(order(x), 3), ]
  ))
)
```

which gives

```
> out
# A tibble: 5 x 4
  cut        freq distance nearest
  <chr>     <dbl>    <dbl> <named list>
1 Very Good   403     14   <tibble [3 x 3]>
2 Fair       3920     25   <tibble [3 x 3]>
3 Premium    5938      5   <tibble [3 x 3]>
4 Good       4593     40   <tibble [3 x 3]>
5 Ideal     21551      2.4 <tibble [3 x 3]>
```

where

```
> out$nearest
$`1`
        cut  freq distance
1      Fair  1610        4
5     Ideal 21551       34
3 Very Good 12082       45

$`2`
        cut  freq distance
5     Ideal 21551       34
3 Very Good 12082       45
1      Fair  1610        4

$`3`
        cut  freq distance
1      Fair  1610        4
5     Ideal 21551       34
3 Very Good 12082       45

$`4`
        cut  freq distance
3 Very Good 12082       45
5     Ideal 21551       34
4   Premium 13791       50

$`5`
        cut  freq distance
1      Fair  1610        4
5     Ideal 21551       34
3 Very Good 12082       45
```